# MySQL Update column Error

Tags: mysql

I want to insert an image path in an existing MySQL column where `id` is max. But it is not working. When I mention any specific id it is working. But I want to insert where id is max. Please help me. I am confused.
I tried with these commands:

```
UPDATE mytable SET image='$path' WHERE id=(SELECT max(id) FROM table)
UPDATE mytable SET image='$path' WHERE id=(SELECT max(id) FROM mytable)
```

None are working.

Comment: What do you mean with `not working`?

Comment: I mean the path is not being saved in the image column.

Comment: i think you can't specify target table  for update in FROM clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql=$mysqli->prepare("select max(id) from tablename");
$sql->execute();
$sql->bind_result($check);
$sql->fetch();
$sql->close();
$sql=$mysqli->prepare("update tablename set imagepath=? where id=?);
$sql->bind_param("si",$imagepath,$check);
$sql->execute();
$sql->close();
```

Comment: This is too complex. Is there any simple method so that i can insert a path in an existing column where id column is max.

Comment: You can't specify target table name for update in FROM clause. This means that you can't give the tablename in where clause in which you are going to do some updation. So, the above solution is simple and easy. Just get the max id and put it in update query.

Comment: You need to do nothing. The check variable will do it for you using php. It will get the max(id) automatically.

Comment: You can also use my another answer below:
UPDATE tablename SET image=  $image  WHERE id = ( SELECT id
FROM (
SELECT MAX( id ) AS id
FROM tablename ) AS t
)

Comment: Some error is coming
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'si' (T_STRING)

Comment: No dear. It is not saving with your second method also. I am surprised that this doesnt have solution.

Comment: Yes Amanjot  ! It is working now with your second method. Thanks a lot buddy !

Answer (score 5):

Please try this query. May this solve your problem.

```
UPDATE mytable SET image='$path' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```